# Change position of a div box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="full-width">
<div class="content-inner vc_col-sm-5">
    <p>This is some text This is some text This is some text</p>
</div>
<div class="slide-show vc_col-sm-7">
    <img src="imageher.jpg" alt="big image">
</div>
```

This is my code, and when window with is smaller than 859px I want to change to possistion of the div boxes.
I want to have the this way:

```
<div class="full-width">
<div class="slide-show vc_col-sm-7">
    <img src="imageher.jpg" alt="big image">
</div>
<div class="content-inner vc_col-sm-5">
    <p>This is some text This is some text This is some text</p>
</div>
```

How do I that jQuery code ?

Comment: you can use [CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to achieve this

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that your question still hasn't a marked solution. Is this because you simply forgot or is your question still unanswered? I'd be happy to help you further with your case, otherwhise please mark this question as solved as it helps other users for a better experience on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually really easy. Just add "float: right" to the "content-inner" as soon as your screen is smaller than 859px.

I posted a fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/q2x5xsu0/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 859px) {
    .content-inner {
      float: right;

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh that dont help really. I have a large website, and my code, is made more simple than it is in real.
So I need to change the position of the div boxes

Comment: I cant help you if you dont show me your website code

Comment: I added:
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;

And now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check window size  like this

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   alert('Less than 960');
}
else {
   alert('More than 960');
}
```

and then change your postion

Comment: But why use jquery for that? And "$(window).width()" is not the css width. You should always use matchmedia https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Thanks, I know that, it is the changing the posistion that I cant't fiqure out to make with javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
write the "JavaScript":

<body onload="fnChange()">
<div class="full-width">
<div class="content-inner vc_col-sm-5" id="dvSmall">
    <p>This is some text This is some text This is some text</p>
</div>
<div class="slide-show vc_col-sm-7" id="dvBig">
    <img src="imageher.jpg" alt="big image">
</div>
</body>
=>Javascript code:
<script>
function fnChange()
{
if(screen.width < 859)
{
$("#dvSmall").insertAfter("#dvBig");
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at the $.resize() api: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

You can get the window size with $(window).width();

So putting that all together

```
<div class="full-width">
<div class="content-inner vc_col-sm-5">
    <p>This is some text This is some text This is some text</p>
</div>
<div class="slide-show vc_col-sm-7">
    <img src="imageher.jpg" alt="big image">
</div>

<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w < 859) {
            //make changes for small configuration
        } else {
            //make changes for large configuration
        }

    });
</script>
```